# How to make a query ignoring special characters in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, case-insensitive

I have a collection of column names that are parameterized. And I would like to make a query with any value from the following collection:

The original and unparameterized collection would be this: (the collection can actually have more than 1000 values ​​with special characters, only put three values):

```
original_array = ["Pizza C&S", "Amal'SQA", "Arcó N spillow"]
```

and parameterizing it would be as follows:

```
original_array.parameterize
=> ["pizza-c-s", "amal-sqa", "arco-n-spillow"]
```

I would like to make a query with the parameterized collection to find the names of the book table.

```
Book.find_by(name: "pizza-c-s") == Book.find_by(name: "Pizza C&S") => 
what i'm looking to do, I just want to search by the parameterized value "pizza-c-s" 
and that it returns the same object as if it were searching for "Pizza C&S"
```

How can I make a query with the parameterized names? since the originals can have any special character

Thanks for reading me and any help is welcome. Happy week to you.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

As pointed out by Will Willson, the values in the DB would have special characters, and they OP wanted a way to search using a parameterized version of the column value. So my answer does not fit their use case, but leaving it for posterity. As Will pointed out it is probably better to store the value parameterized in another column so it can easily be searched.

---

If I understand you correctly you are looking for something like:

```
Book.find_by(name: "Pizza C&S".parameterize)
```

Comment: No, I have to make queries with the parameterized values.

original_value = "Pizza C&S"

parameterize_value = original_value.parameterize ;; "pizza-c-s" (parameterize remove special characters)

Book.find_by(name: parameterize_value) ;; is what i try to do
Book.find_by("name LIKE ?", "%#{parameterize_value}%")

Book.find_by(name: parameterize_value) should be equal that Book.find_by(name: original_value)

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't understand your comment. The code I gave you will search the DB for "pizza-c-s". If you tried it then what happened?

Comment: Don't worry. In my DB I have a name column called "Pizza C&S" from the Book model.

"Pizza C&S" string is parameterized, becoming "pizza-c-s"

With the parameterized string I must make a new query to Book.find_by(name: "pizza-c-s") or Book.find_by(name: "Pizza C&S".parameterize)

Of course, when doing the search with the parameterized value, it will return NIL and not the object that I want to search for.

I am looking at the way to make queries to the name already parameterized

I have tried to do SQL queries directly but I can't find the way to return the object neither

Comment: can you add a 'slug' column to the table and store the parameterized value there? Then query by slug instead of by name

Comment: I feel like a dumb xD, that's what I was looking for. Thank you so much for your answer @WillWilson

Comment: @WillWilson I like your answer, I was going under the assumption that they wouldn't want to change DB schema. But can you explain to me why my answer wouldn't work? It seems like a trivial problem. What am I missing? Also thanks for the reminder that there's nothing wrong with adding a column if it makes things simpler!

Comment: @Beartech the name would be "Pizza C&S".  The parameterized value, created by the `parameterize` method, would be "pizza-c-s". So your answer would query for `name: 'pizza-c-s'` which does not exist in the database.  The question is not 100% clear about this but the name is saved with special characters, then transformed in memory using the `parameterize` method.

Comment: AH!! I was taking it to mean the reverse, that they had parameterized it before saving. Now it makes sense. Thanks!